# type 'DateTime' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' Flutter and firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

so i have a function that get data from firebase firestore for my chat app i wanted to add pagination to it.

i created this function :

```
getMessage() {
if (!hasMore) {
  return;
}
if (isLoading) {
  return;
}
if (lastDoc == null) {
  _querySnapshot = widget.messageDocRef
      .collection('Chat')
      .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
      .limit(15)
      .getDocuments();
} else if (lastDoc != null) {
  _querySnapshot = widget.messageDocRef
      .collection('Chat')
      .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
      .startAfter(
          lastDoc.data['timestamp'].toDate().add(Duration(hours: 1)))
      .limit(15)
      .getDocuments();
}
_querySnapshot.then((docSnap) {
  lastDoc = docSnap.documents[docSnap.documents.length - 1];
  print(lastDoc);
  print(lastDoc.data['content']);
  print(lastDoc.data['timestamp'].toDate().add(Duration(hours: 1)));
});
return _querySnapshot.asStream();
```

}

this line print the correct time that is stored in firestore.

> print(lastDoc.data['timestamp'].toDate().add(Duration(hours: 1)));

but for some reason when i try to load more messages with

> startAfter(
>                 lastDoc.data['timestamp'].toDate().add(Duration(hours: 1)))

the screens becomes Red with this error message : **type 'DateTime' is not a subtype of type 'List'**

i've tried with **lastDoc.data['timestamp']**  & with **lastDoc.data['timestamp'].toDate()** and with **lastDoc.data['timestamp'].toDate().add(Duration(hours: 1))** but nothing happened and the same error occurs.

***NOTE*** that i am assigning getMessage() to a streamBuilder.

this is my StreamBuilder

```
StreamBuilder(
  //TODO add pagination later...
  stream: getMessages(),
  /*stream: widget.messageDocRef
      .collection('Chat')
      .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
      .limit(80)
      .getDocuments()
      .asStream(),*/
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Center(
        child: circularProgress(),
      );
    }
    final messages = snapshot.data.documents;

    List<MessageBubble> messagesBubble = [];
    for (var message in messages) {
      final messageText = message.data['content'];

      final messageSender = message.data['from'];

      final messageType = message.data['type'];

      final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
        type: messageType,
        text: messageText,
        isMe: widget.currentUser.id == messageSender,
      );
      messagesBubble.add(messageBubble);
    }
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView(
        physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        reverse: true,
        controller: _scrollController,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 10.0),
        children: messagesBubble,
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

startAfter takes `List` of type `dynamic` as an input so wrap `lastDoc.data['timestamp'].toDate().add(Duration(hours: 1))` inside a list `[]`.

Also since you've the documents list handy in that function, you could you use: `startAfterDocument`  such in:

```
 _querySnapshot = widget.messageDocRef
      .collection('Chat')
      .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
      .startAfterDocument(lastDoc)
```

I hope that helps.

Here's a good video from Firebase team on YouTube explains pagination:

[How Do I Paginate My Data?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poqTHxtDXwU)

And this page is a good resource from Firestore docs:

[Paginating data with query cursors](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/query-cursors)

Comment: Hi, thanks for you response, unfortunately it's not working there is no error. but when i scroll to the end of the list view the second query get called but nothing happens, but when click hot reload the old messages appears!!

Comment: It's hard to tell since there could be a lot of reasons (no data matching the filter for example) but also how are reading the code... So when you run the app for the first time, nothing appears but when you hot reload the old messages appears? Are you using StatelessWidget to show the data?

Comment: No i'm using statefull. When i navigate to the chat page the 15 first message loads from firebase that's what i want. But when i scroll to the end of the listview (older message should load) nothing happens till i hot reload!!

Comment: Can you update your question with code of the ListView?